# Get the first value from a list of values a table index

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

My input is a two column table with headers `_id` and `change_num`. `change_num` is a string of comma-separated numbers that correspond to change IDs. For example:

```
    _id     change_num
    123     4354, 3243, 7893
    456     920, 1232, 9834, 2323
```

I want to get the first value in each row of `change_num`, so my output looks like this:

```
    _id     change_num
    123     4354
    456     920
```

How can I stop at the first comma and neglect everything thereafter? Furthermore, if a `change_num` starts with `CN`, can I ignore it and just get the number?

```
    _id     change_num
    123     CN4354, 3243, 7893
    456     920, 1232, 9834, 2323
```

to return

```
    _id     change_num
    123     4354
    456     920
```

Comment: think you should restructure your data to use a link-table..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is string manipulation.  Something like this should work:

```
select t.id,
       replace(substr(change_num, 1, instr(change_num, ',') - 1), 'CN', '')
from table t;
```

As you can tell, storing ids in a comma-separated list is a bad idea.  If you have any control over the data structure, you should add a junction table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT _id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(change_num, ',', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the REGEXP_SUBSTR function in oracle 10 or later (or an appropriate function in other db) and use regex to query the data that you want:

```
select _id, REGEXP_SUBSTR(change_num, '\d+') from tablet;
```